# Making an animation class be added and executed after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a flash cards animation on a website so I attempted to add an animation class after 5 seconds but the class dosent come into affect unless I do something like an alert box. Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("#webDesign").addClass("animated");
      $("#webDesign").addClass("bounceOutDown");
      location.reload();
    }, 5000);
  });
```

```css
#webDesign{
  height:20em;
  background-color:white;
  opacity:0.8;
  border:1.5px solid black;
  border-radius:30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<head>
  <body>
 <div id="webDesign" class="card text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h2>Web Desgin</h2>
      <h5>Through paying close attention to our customer's needs we make the websites that fit them best.</h5>
      <img style="width:40%;"src="pictures/webDesign.png"  />
    </div>
   </body>
```

This is my first time using this website, I will appreciate any help anyone is willing to offer.

Comment: you didnt declare those animation classes on your css, so obviously they won't do anything

Comment: They are in a separate css file. animate.css you can look them up

Comment: Why not simply set a delay on the animation instead? ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: post your whole code them

Answer (score 0):

If you define transition on "animated" class and effect on "bounceOutDown" you need to put the class addition onto separate timeouts as otherwise both classes are added together and you have no transition from browser perspective. Not sure as you didn't paste those classes, but lets try it like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout($("#webDesign").addClass, 5000, "animated");
  setTimeout($("#webDesign").addClass, 5010, "bounceOutDown");
  setTimeout(location.reload, 5020);
});
```

10 ms between operations is just fine.